# When creating a multiple regression model for a subgroup, is it necessary to test all assumptions again?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, assumptions, diagnostic

My results section consists of a multiple regression analysis considering 3 factors, containing all of my participants. Following this, I have considered males and females separately, by construction of further multiple regression models containing the same variables as the first model, but only containing male or female participants.

I have already demonstrated that data from the whole cohort meets all of the relevant assumptions (outliers, collinearity, independant errors, non-zero variances, normally distributed errors, homogeneity and linearity). I was wondering whether I need to run all of these test again for both of the subgroups, or do any of the results 'carry over' from the tests for the whole set of participants?

Comment: Welcome to our site! This is a really nice first question.

Comment: If the tests did not break the data down into subgroups, then there is no universal relationship between their results for the whole dataset and their results for the subgroups: for every test you mention, it is possible to construct an example where the subgroups *strongly* violate the assumption but the overall data exhibit no violation at all (when the subgroup information is ignored, at least).